# anchor tag is not properly working in my Laravel site

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, anchor

In my Laravel site I want to link up my facebook account with the website but it is not working properly.
If I am using

```
<a href="{{url('/www.facebook.com/my_fb_page_id')}}"></a>
```

for that, link shown like this

> https://myDomainName/www.facebook.com/my_fb_page_id

But if I want to show only the facebook link with my fb id, for that I have used

```
<a href="www.facebook.com/my_fb_page_id"></a>
```

For that also the link shown same like below

> https://myDomainName/www.facebook.com/my_fb_page_id

Where is my fault. Can't figure it out.

Anybody help please ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use links like this it will work fine
    https://facebook.com/my_fb_page_id
    [my page](https://facebook.com/my_fb_page_id)

Answer (score 1):

Try prepending `http://` or `https://`  to the URL.

It looks to be a problem with local and absolute URLs

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/my_fb_page_id"></a>
```

Comment: ....Brother thanks for your cooperation. You both are correct. But because Omar have give the answer first that's why i accept his answer....

Comment: He deserves it. I didn't see his answer before. Appreciated.